# Is it possible to pass a float array to an iOS SceneKit vertex shader modifier?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, scenekit, glsles

I'm working with SceneKit on iOS. In an OpenGL ES vertex shader I'm trying to read the following uniform:

```
uniform float floats[8];
```

I'm passing my array to the vertex shader modifier using to following call in Swift:

```
let floats = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0]
material.setValue(NSArray(array: floats), forKey: "floats")
```

However, whatever I do, it seems like the uniform is just initialized to an array of zeroes.

Is passing arrays to shader modifiers supported? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I also need to pass a float array to my shader modifier

Answer (score 2):

NO, passing `NSArray` to uniform is not supported, based this table from [`SCNShadable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnshadable) manual:

[image]

But you could use two `vec4 (SCNVector4)` or `mat4 (CATransform3D)`, but remember to wrap them in `NSValue`.

The other way would be try something like this:

```
let vec1 = SCNVector4(x: 10.0, y: 20.0, z: 30.0, w: 40.0)
let vec2 = SCNVector4(x: 50.0, y: 60.0, z: 70.0, w: 80.0)
let unival = NSValue(bytes: [vec1, vec2], objCType: "[2{SCNVector4=ffff}]")
material.setValue(unival, forKey: "floats")
```

This make use of [type encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100-SW1) of `NSValue`'s [`init(bytes:objCType:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsvalue/1411621-init), and theoretically *should* work as long as value is correctly encoded.

Comment: Hi, with your second approach (using type encoding), how would I go about accessing the individual elements within the shader modifier code?  What would the type definition of the universal value be for example? (If I would guess it would be "uniform float floats[8];")