# SCNShadable in SceneKit pass float array to shader modifier

Tags: swift, glsl, shader, scenekit, metal

I am using [SCNShadable's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable) shader modifiers in SceneKit. I want to pass an array of float vectors (float3's).

In the SCNShadable docs, under the section *"Providing Custom Inputs to a Shader Modifier"*, the following table is presented with data type conversions:

[image]

To pass a value to the shader, one must wrap the value in one of the specified types. It does not seem as array types are supported, but only `NSValue`,`NSNumber` or `SCMaterialProperty` types.

In the shader, you also need to define the type which you pass. As an example, I might wish to define something like:

```
uniform vec3 points[100];
```

Is it really not possible to pass a float array to initialize this uniform?

Otherwise, I thought that maybe it would be possible to store a float3 array as a texture in the `SCNMaterialProperty` type and pass this. However, I am unsure about how I might access the individual float3 values in the shader then.

Here are other similar questions I saw that might be relevant:

[SceneKit shader modifiers with GLSL arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888445/scenekit-shader-modifiers-with-glsl-arrays)

[Is it possible to pass a float array to an iOS SceneKit vertex shader modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109613/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-float-array-to-an-ios-scenekit-vertex-shader-modifier)

Answer (score 4):

the online documentation is not up to date. The `SCNShadable.h` header also mentions `NSData` and `id <MTLBuffer>` that can both be used for arrays.

```
GLSL        | Metal Shading Language | Objective-C                           |
------------┼------------------------┼---------------------------------------┤
-           | device const T*        | MTLBuffer                             | Feature introduced in macOS 10.13, iOS 11.0 and tvOS 11.0
-           | struct {...}           | NSData                                | The entire struct can be set using NSData but it is also possible to set individual members using the member's name as a key and a value compatible with the member's type
```

Comment: Oh, good news then! So provided I wrap my float array as an NSData object and pass it through what I presume should be SCNMaterial.setValue(), how do I define the uniform type in the shader in GLSL/metal code?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently poorly documented but here's what worked for me.

You can pass the values over using a [`MTLBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlbuffer). To do this, first in your shader modifier, defined your buffer argument. This should be a pointer to the buffer type (in this case I have a buffer of `float` values):

```swift
geometry.firstMaterial?.shaderModifiers = [
    .geometry:
        """
        #pragma arguments
        float* buffer;

        #pragma body
        // Shader body
        """
]
```

`SCNShadable.h` suggests that `device const float*` should work but I found that adding the `device` qualifier causes a shader compile error.

Then set the buffer on your material:

```swift
geometry.firstMaterial?.setValue(myBuffer, forKey: "buffer")
```

Using this approach, I am able to pass an `MTLBuffer` of any type of data to the shaderModifiers

Comment: I can't get this to work, I just get values of all 0 in the actual shader itself. I'm making the buffer like `mtlDevice.makeBuffer(bytes: myArray, length: MemoryLayout<SIMD3<Float>>.stride * myArray.count)` and passing in the length separately. But every subscript just returns 0.